# Should I first configure my new Ubuntu Server install before updating it?

Tags: server, upgrade, configuration

I'm courious if there is any recommendation to configure fresh Ubuntu Server (date, hosts, networking) before "apt-get upgrade" or there is no difference?

Answer (score 7):

Update everything first. Some upgrades will often ask you if you want to replace your configuration files with their new default configurations, and that  can be a headache to decide.

Save yourself the trouble; update first, then configure. The only exception should be choosing a custom update mirror :)

Comment: Thaks for the answer :)

Comment: In that case, please consider accepting it (tick/check mark on the left) so that the question is closed and marked as "answered" to help future readers. Thanks!